# PHP multidimensional array sort matching values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my multidimensional array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-01 [1] => active [2] => 345 )
[1] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-01 [1] => not_active [2] => 337 )
[2] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-01 [1] => active [2] => 328 )
[3] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-02 [1] => not_active [2] => 312 )
[4] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-02 [1] => active [2] => 338 )
[5] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-02 [1] => active [2] => 346 ) 
[6] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-03 [1] => not_active [2] => 317 ) 
[7] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-03 [1] => active [2] => 339 ) 
[8] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-04 [1] => active [2] => 340 )
[9] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-04 [1] => not_active [2] => 318 ) 
[10] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-05 [1] => active [2] => 322 )
[11] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-05 [1] => not_active [2] => 341 ) 
[12] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-06 [1] => active [2] => 342 ) 
[13] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-06 [1] => active [2] => 325 )
[14] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-07 [1] => active [2] => 343 ) 
[15] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-07 [1] => active [2] => 326 )
 )
```

There is 7 days, but 16 records. I'm trying to create a loop to combine records with same dates to have 7 records array. 
To look like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-01  [1] => active [2] => 345 [3] => 2015-06-01 [4] => not_active [5] => 337[6] => 2015-06-01  [7] => active [8] => 328)
[1] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-02 [1] => not_active [2] => 312 [3] => 2015-06-02 [4] => active [5] => 338 [6] => 2015-06-02 [7] => active [8] => 346)
[2] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-03 [1] => not_active [2] => 317 [3] => 2015-06-03 [4] => active [5] => 339  ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-04 [1] => active [2] => 340 [3] => 2015-06-04    [4] => not_active [5] => 318)
[4] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-05 [1] => active [2] => 322 [3] => 2015-06-05 [4] => not_active [5] => 341  )
[5] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-06 [1] => active [2] => 342 [3] => 2015-06-06 [4] => active [5] => 325  ) 
[6] => Array ( [0] => 2015-06-07 [1] => active [2] => 343 [3] => 2015-06-07 [4] => active [5] => 326) 
)
```

Comment: Why to hold the redundancies?

Comment: post what you've tried. what you've read.

Comment: can you post a cleaner version of the array to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following uses the "dates" as the keys in the final output array:

```
<?php
// Initializing
$arr = [
    ['2015-06-01', 'active',     345],
    ['2015-06-01', 'not_active', 337],
    ['2015-06-01', 'active',     328],
    ['2015-06-02', 'not_active', 312],
    ['2015-06-02', 'active',     338],
    ['2015-06-02', 'active',     346],
    ['2015-06-03', 'not_active', 317],
    ['2015-06-03', 'active',     339],
    ['2015-06-04', 'active',     340],
    ['2015-06-04', 'not_active', 318],
    ['2015-06-05', 'active',     322],
    ['2015-06-05', 'not_active', 341],
    ['2015-06-06', 'active',     342],
    ['2015-06-06', 'active',     325],
    ['2015-06-07', 'active',     343],
    ['2015-06-07', 'active',     326],
];
// The heart of the code:
$out = array();
foreach($arr as $element) {
    foreach($element as $val)
        $out[$element[0]][] = $val;
}
// Printing
echo "<pre>";
print_r($out);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

However, if you want the keys of the output array to be indexed sequentially, then you may also use the following code segment:

```
$out2 = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($out as $element)
    $out2[$i++] = $element;
// Printing
echo "<hr>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($out2);
echo "</pre>";
```